# Need help in running select statement in a perl script

Tags: sql, database, windows, perl

```
$START_PRI_AA=1;

$expression = "$SQLPLUS_DIR\\$SQLPLUS_EXEC -S $PLANSTAGE_DB_USER/$PLANSTAGE_DB_PASSWORD\@$PLANSTAGE_DB_ALIAS  
        'set pagesize 0
        set feedback off
        set verify off
        set heading off
        set echo off 
        select STATUS from jdaabppd.DFXHA_ENGINE_STATUS where ENGINE_NAME ='$ENV{PRI_AA_ENGINE}';
        exit;
        /'
        ";

print "\n\n expression is $expression \n\n";
$status = system($expression);

print "$status\n\n";
```

Comment: What is your question? And please post the output of the script, including error messages. And try adding semi-colons between the SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

Why use SQLPLUS from within Perl, while it already has excellent modules to interact with databases ?

First of all you need to install modules [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) and [DBD::Oracle](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Oracle), and then you can do something like :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "dbi:Oracle:host=locahost;port=1521;sid=$PLANSTAGE_DB_ALIAS",  # DSN of the database to connect 
    $PLANSTAGE_DB_USER,      # username
    $PLANSTAGE_DB_PASSWORD,  # password
    { RaiseError => 1 }      # die on any DBI error
);

my ($status) = $dbh->selectrow_array(
    "select STATUS from jdaabppd.DFXHA_ENGINE_STATUS where ENGINE_NAME ='?", # your sql query
    undef,                 # no specific options needed 
    $ENV{PRI_AA_ENGINE}    # bind value
);
```

You may need to adjust the DSN according to your use case, I made a few assumptions based on the code snippet you showed. Read the DBI docs for more details.